# Javascript: Run setInterval only once

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, setinterval

I would like to run the following code only once, so after 2 seconds it will change the iframe's src, but won't try to do it again and again.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function () {document.getElementById('iframe').src = "http://www.y.com";}, 2000);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You're looking for `setTimeout()`, which does exactly that.

Answer (score 16):

yep...

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
        // code to run after 5 seconds...
}, 5000);
```

or by taking your method to outer context

```
function myMethod(){
    // code to run after 5 seconds...
};

window.setTimeout(myMethod, 5000);
```

The latter is useful if you have a method you don't plan to execute ONLY wit that timeout.

Comment: 2nd method yet not correct, it runs immediately, and again after 5 seconds, if `myMethod` would return a reference to a function :-(.

Comment: Hmm... only you'd needed to do is to remove parenthesis from the `myMethod()` --> `window.setTimeout(myMethod, 5000);`, though this is a good form when you need to pass arguments to `myMethod()`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout), you can see more details in Mozilla site.